# Windows 7 has blue screens after updates

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I have Windows 7, and yesterday I did some updates. Today when I started the computer I find myself having blue screens constantly after I log in, for no apparent reason at all.

I entered the computer in safe mode with network and couldn't find anything to help me. Now I am trying to use a restoration point, but I am not sure if windows made one.

After checking the details of the crash, this is what Windows tells me:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    2070

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   50
  BCP1: B5FAC000
  BCP2: 00000000
  BCP3: 82A6244B
  BCP4: 00000000
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  256_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\030816-26437-01.dmp
  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-60671-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

The sysdata.xml file can be accessed here:
http://pasted.co/9799b3b6

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you share the file **C:\Windows\Minidump\030816-26437-01.dmp**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that before "critical updates" windows creates a **restore point**. 
Retauring the machine to the previous state of the update solved the problem.

Sure I won't have the update, but between that and having a BSOD every 10 minutes, I choose the first one.

Hope this helps others.